# Can xlsxwriter use another file as a template?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Can xlsxwriter object use a template of another excel file?

I tried to use xlsr but it can't use a template.

I am using xlsxwriter since I am writing more the 65335 lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the XlsxWriter [FAQ](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html):

> **Q. Can XlsxWriter use an existing Excel file as a template?**
>
> No.
>
> XlsxWriter is designed only as a file *writer*. It cannot read or modify an existing Excel file.

[OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can read and rewrite files and handle the Excel 2007 format.